# IDE expecting file to be in different location

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

I have a component package in Delphi XE2 version 16.0.4429.46931, both a run-time and design-time package together. This package has existed for over a year, and the file/folder structure has always been the same. I keep all the units in a dedicated `Source` folder from the root, and the actual packages in a `Packages` folder in the same root. So the packages are found in `\Root\Packages\` and units are found in `\Root\Source\`.

Today, after building the run-time package, I was going through the hints and warnings. One of the warnings was this:

```
[DCC Warning] Inno.TimeChart.pas(1): W1025 Unsupported language feature: 'class constructor'
```

The warning its self is not what worries me. The problem is when I double-click this warning, I get an error message from the IDE:

[image: IDE Error Message]

The one thing which I immediately noticed was that it is not looking in the `Source` folder, but rather directly in the `Packages` folder. Somehow, the IDE is expecting that the unit be in the same location as the package. Ever since I created the package over a year ago, I have never changed any of the library paths, locations of files, or structure of the package.

The file does exist, but in a different place than it appears to be looking. The file has never been saved in the folder with the projects, and in fact nothing other than the package projects themselves have ever been saved in the `Packages` folder. This all resides in the `Source` folder, but the IDE seems to think otherwise.

Why would the IDE think this file is in a different folder? All the other hints and warnings related to the same unit work just fine when I double-click them, but not this one.

**EDIT**

I've created a new test package to troubleshoot this issue.

```
Root\TestPackage.dpr
Root\Source\TestPackageUnit.pas
```

The specific piece of code which is causing this compiler warning is in this class:

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  strict private
    class constructor Create;
  end;
```

When I compile, using Process Monitor, I see the IDE is searching in 30+ different places for this file (of course failing), it looks like it's searching in every library path, rather than in the one place the package says it's at.

**Things I've Tried**

1. Verified there is no difference between these paths between the `DPR` and `DPROJ` files
2. Installed all the latest updates and the IDE FixPack (actually gave me new problems)
3. Monitored file's access with Process Monitor

   1. Filters: process name equals `BDS.exe`; Path ends with `TestPackageUnit.pas`
   2. Result: "NAME NOT FOUND" --> Desired Access: Generic Read Disposition: Open Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File Attributes: N ShareMode: Read, Write AllocationSize: n/a
4. Tried with designtime-only, runtime-only, and designtime/runtime combined
5. Tried with component registered and unregistered
6. Tried with directory in library path and not in library path
7. Removed about 20 unnecessary entries from library path to make it shorter
8. Moved directory to top of library path
9. Verified there is no `DOF` file associated with project (That I think is from older versions)
10. Restarted IDE and computer number of times
11. Cleaned up compiled and temporary files from project, including BPL and DCU files
12. Changed `strict private` to just `private` and even `public`

Comment: Hard to say, maybe your package source does not contain the path to this source file in `contains` clause, maybe you need to restart IDE. Sure IDE should find source files if it compiles them.

Comment: Check it! Log what folders are actually checked for the file.
I had experience when Delphi could not build my BPLs into `$(OutputPathVar)` - but restart fixed it. And i saw issues where installers enforced 64-bit paths into 32-bit Delphi environment, deleting original paths. There may be a lot of troubles, but logging would at last give you soem idea what is really happening.

Comment: SysInternals.com filters: process name, equal, BDS.exe (or how your delphi is called); path, ends with, your file name. On the toolbar press *filesystem operations* button and unpress all the rest

Comment: Jerry, what is the structure of the DPK, are you using relative paths that point to the units?

Comment: In the worst case you could met an ICE - internal compiler error. I met situations when Unit1 was used by Unit2 and Unit1 triggered ICE. but it was reported against head of Unit2 instead. But that was not about warning but about clear ICE. BTW, the very text of warning seems strange to me. In which condition class constructors might be unsupported by XE2 ? C++ headers emitting ? Extended Syntax shut off ? the very text or the warning makes me curious

Comment: @Arioch'The I've cleaned up my comments and moved those detail to the question, so I'd suggest you delete your comments as well which are no longer relevant.

Comment: Very odd. Often, the IDE cannot find source, because they are not installed, or not configured in the library path. This is, of course, to prevent them from being recompiled everytime while must Delphi users wouldn't need that. But if they give you a warning, that is because the file is compiled anyway. The only reason I can think of is that the command line compiler (DCC, which gives you the error) is using a different set of paths than the IDE itself. @Arioch'The is probably right about a difference sneeking in between the dpr and the dproj file.

Comment: Can anyone verify this issue on another installation of RAD Studio XE2? No word yet of anyone else's success or failure trying to recreate this.

Comment: @JerryDodge TestPackageUnit.pas is not the file in the error message...

Comment: @GolezTrol That's because this is another test package I created explicitly for testing this issue.

Comment: did u try changing class constructor to `public` or just `private` ?

Comment: Changing to just `private` did not work either.

Comment: Would it be more proper to say the `DCC` is having problems, and not necessarily the `IDE`?

Comment: Could it be that the filepath is described in the windows registry somewhere?

Comment: @MichielT Why would a brand new project in a brand new never-before-existing directory somehow be somewhere in the Windows registry? Even if it's so, how would this contribute to the problem? The registry is a huge thing.

Comment: No solution found to award bounty to, I'm just giving up on this, it's not any critical show stopper, but it is real puzzling.

Answer (score 3):

I do run into such problems when the delphi search path list is too long. I could always help myself in moving the relevant directories more to the front, i.e. up in the list.

Comment: +1, I thought this would fix it, so I removed almost 20 unnecessary directories from the library path, but I still have the same issue. There's a total of 33 directories there now, with 1,740 total characters. Is that still too long?

Comment: Honestly, I never counted the characters. Does moving the path to the top of the list does not help?

Comment: Tried that, but no it didn't help. It shouldn't have anything to do with the library paths anyway, because at this point, it's only compiling the package. It's not like some external project is trying to reference this package, this package its self doesn't know where its own file is. It shouldn't even try to look in the library path.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the file has not been added to the project file (dpr or dpk). Project - View Source will display the file.

If this isn't the case, try searching all the files in your project for the file name and see what turns up.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on another website:

> There is another QC that is probably linked to your problem.
>   http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=87693
>
> Go to Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Output C/C++ and under
>   C/C++ output file generation select Generate DCUs only.
>
> Dalija Prasnikar

Source: [http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.general](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.general/class-constructors-in-package-delp/1056448)

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).